# Simulating a submit and validation to a separate form on AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to simulate submit plus **validation** on a form whose button is outside of it?

It can be done with this:

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <form ng-submit="onSubmitted()">

    Header inputs:
        <input type="name" ng-model="sample" required/>
        <input type="name" ng-model="sampleX" required/>

        <div style="visibility: hidden">
        <input type="submit" id="clcikMe" value="This submit triggers validation. But I wanted to put this button at the end of the page"/>
        </div>
    </form>

    <hr/>

    Some other form here. Think line items

    <hr />
    <a class="btn" linked="clcikMe">Wanted this submit button to trigger the validation+submit on the form in which this button doesn't belong</a>



</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.onSubmitted = function() {
        alert('submitted!');
    };

}
app.directive("linked",function(){
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var id = attrs["linked"];
        element.on("click",function(){
            document.getElementById(id).click();
        });
    };
});
```

---

But I wanted to stay away from that approach, it's very kludgy, it triggers a validation+submit by simulating a submit on first form by clicking its hidden submit button

Is there an API on AngularJS (or even plain javascript) that will let me achieve my objective? I.e. without using any hidden submit button

Comment: I see you are still seeking for solution. I have to tell you one thing. If you submit form `$("#someFormElement").submit()` from javascript, it cannot execute browser builtin client validation, but you can check validity of your form `$("#someFormElement")[0].checkValidity()` which returns true/false. Tho,  You could go trough all input elements and do same check `checkValidity` but still all that is manual work

Comment: @MilanJaric I have an inkling that there's an AngularJS hook for the functionality I'm seeking :-) I'm not seeking to do `$("#someFormElement").submit()` if it cannot execute the validations. I hope there's an angular way to trigger the validation on form prior to calling the submit's controller's action, conjuring something along this line: `$("#someFormElement").ngSubmit()` :-)

Comment: It's not framework agnostic issue, its how validation is implemented in browsers. It was done in that manner to left developers room for customization. It is feature :) I know it sound crazy but there are other examples like if select tag selection is changed from javascript code (the index) it will not fire change event of select tag... So you have to hide button and click it if you want built in browser validation mechanism

Answer (score 0):

You're not thinking very Angular here. No one is forcing you to work with form ng-submit. Just use 2 buttons each with their own `ng-click="runThisFunction()"` or simply use the same function and pass along a parameter. i.e:

```
<button ng-click="submitForm(true)">Validate + Submit</button>
```

and

```
<button ng-click="submitForm(false)">Only Validate</button>
```

Then in your controller:

```
$scope.submitForm = function(shouldSubmit) {
    //run validation here.
    //either using $scope.form.name.$valid or ng-model $scope variable
    var dataGood = false;
    if ($scope.sample === "goodData" && $scope.sample === "alsoGoodData" ) {
        //data is good
        dataGood = true;
        //alert user that data is good!
        alert('good job, your data is great!');
    }
    else {
    //data is bad
         alert (' data bad, dear padowan');
    }

    if (!shouldSubmit) return;

    //perform $http request to server, or navigate to a different page or whatever
    if (dataGood) {
    //submit data to server and let the party begin
    $http.post('/api/rocknroll/submit', { sample: $scope.sample, sampleX: $scope.sampleX}).then( $scope.handleResponse);
    }
}
```

This will work whether or not you're in the scope of the form, but you need to be in the scope of the controller.

Comment: Your question was not: "How do you validate data", but it was "how to process form data and submit based on a button outside form scope". So yeah. But I edited it so that you can read better.